# Why do vector::iterator and set::iterator work different?

Tags: c++, iterator

Why can I do this

```
vector<int> a;
//...
cout << a.end()-a.begin();
```

But I can't do the same with set::iterator?

Comment: The dupe target talks about `std::map` but `std::set` is exactly the same in this regard.

Comment: there different [categories of iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator)

Comment: Specifically, `std::vector` iterators are [random access iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator), while for `std::set` they are only [bidirectional iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator).

Comment: Eventually we will be able to ask this nicely once we get the `contiguous_iterator` of C++20. IMHO you can do this with a vector in a defined way prior to C++20 by a fortunate accident (or by knowing more about the way in which `std::vector` is required to organise itself): subtracting pointers is only defined behaviour if they point to elements within the same array. Reopened as IMHO the "duplicate" was more of a reference than anything else.

Comment: @Bathsheba: That doesn't sound right, because nobody is talking about pointers.  `a.end()-a.begin()` is also well defined for `std::dequeue`, even though it's _not_ contiguous.

Comment: Closer possible dupe: [C++ Set: No match for - operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13515261/1782792)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why do vector::iterator and set::iterator work different?

Because one container has fast random access and the other does not. And because as a consequence, one iterator is a random access iterator and the other is not. Bidirectional iterators are not guaranteed to support subtraction.

You can achieve the same with `std::distance` which works with all input iterators. But you need to be aware that it has linear complexity for non-random access iterators.